# Referencing subfigures/Increasing figure counter

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, subfloats, subcaption

There is a problem with referencing subfigures.

[image]

When I add the line containing `\caption{}`, everything works perfect, but caption of a figure must be below the figure.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}
\begin{figure}
\caption{} % When I add this line, everything works perfect, but caption of a figure must be below the figure.
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
1A
\captionof{subfigure}{1A}
\label{fig:1:A}  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
1B
\captionof{subfigure}{1B}
\label{fig:1:B}  
\end{minipage}
\caption{First~\ref{fig:1:A}~\ref{fig:1:B}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
2A
\captionof{subfigure}{2A}
\label{fig:2:A}  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
2B
\captionof{subfigure}{2B}
\label{fig:2:B}  
\end{minipage}
\caption{First~\ref{fig:2:A}~\ref{fig:2:B}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note 1: The real document has 3500 lines so I can not set the value of the figure counter manually via `\renewcommand\thefigure{2}`.

Note 2: In a single figure of the real document, there are plenty of `minipage`s that contain tikz pictures so I prefer using minipage.

Comment: Any considerations changing the minipages to `subfigures` and using the standard `caption` command as described in the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cubcaption manual hints to use the command `subcaption` instead of captionof. It increases the counters internally. Another possibility would be to use the provided environment `subfigure` (it uses a minipage itself and got the same syntax, you could just do a string replace) along with the caption command we all know.

Both of the following MWEs produce the same end result.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
%\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
1A
\subcaption{1A}
\label{fig:1:A}  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
1B
\subcaption{1B}
\label{fig:1:B}  
\end{minipage}
\caption{First~\ref{fig:1:A}~\ref{fig:1:B}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
2A
\subcaption{2A}
\label{fig:2:A}  
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
2B
\subcaption{2B}
\label{fig:2:B}  
\end{minipage}
\caption{First~\ref{fig:2:A}~\ref{fig:2:B}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Using subfigure:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        1A
        \caption{1A}
        \label{fig:1:A}  
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        1B
        \caption{1B}
        \label{fig:1:B}  
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{First~\ref{fig:1:A}~\ref{fig:1:B}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        2A
        \caption{2A}
        \label{fig:2:A}  
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.50\textwidth}
        2B
        \caption{2B}
        \label{fig:2:B}  
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{First~\ref{fig:2:A}~\ref{fig:2:B}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```